# Highchart Different points are showing for simmer value in the tooltip after zoom in

Tags: highcharts, angular5

I am getting deffernt points in graph after doing zoom in like showing for 0 showing mutiple places for same vlaue for x and y axis.

after adding
**dataGrouping: {
enabled: false
}**

**Getting Following Error:**
Type '{ dataGrouping: { enabled: false; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dataGrouping' does not exist in type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGsZS.png)

Comment: Hello, Could you add more details about the problem? You have probably loaded wrong types for a chart. Please try to use `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';`.

Comment: I might be not able to expalin the problem properly. The problem is  multiple 0 is coming in x axis points when we do more zoom .

Comment: I have added image for better understanding which is showing multipe 0 on x axis. can you please help now?

Comment: I thought that the problem is related with TypeScript. For better understanding please reproduce the case in jsfiddle, you can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: This has been fixed, found issue due to data formating I am going from KB to MB and fixing to 1 place only. update decimal places from 1 to 3.
Thanks.